# WSDOT Traveler Information API - Anybody know how to access the below url with parameters like limit, offset etc

Tags: api

API list: http://wsdot.wa.gov/traffic/api/

There are some class documentation, but they are not telling how to access those functions.

http://wsdot.wa.gov/traffic/api/Documentation/index.html

Get highway alerts: http://wsdot.wa.gov/traffic/api/Documentation/class_highway_alerts.html#a3b45c057c4cea9d8953d917d0a183e94

Answer (score 1):

Go to this page, it will list the different kinds of responses you can get and the URL to call with your parameters such as limit and offset. Then push GET to see an example response
http://wsdot.wa.gov/traffic/api/HighwayAlerts/HighwayAlertsREST.svc/Help